# Индексирование Foreign key при создании в PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

Ситуация следующая:

Используем PostgreSQL 9.4.

Есть большая таблица messages_conversationpart (72 млн. строк, ~60Gb данных, столько же индексов).
Необходимо добавить к ней ForeignKey на новую только что созданную messages_conversationpartgroup. По-умолчанию, значение поля должно быть NULL.

В бэкенде используется django 1.8. Makemigrations нагенерила следующий SQL для создания индекса:

```
 CREATE INDEX "messages_conversationpart_ad8eec18" ON messages_conversationpart" ("part_group_id");
```

При попытке выполнить данную миграцию на боевой базе все упало =(. Миграция была отменена, стали искать причины.
Выяснилось, что индекс создается долго, да еще создает локи на всю таблицу (хотя, казалось бы, nullable поле на пустую таблицу - что там индексировать то?). В тестовом окружении на полной реплике боевой базы без нагрузки - индекс создавался 2 минуты, после чего его создание было прервано, за очевидной долгостью процесса. В pg_stat_activity висит state='idle in transaction' у данного запроса.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks ;
```

Возвращает, что все локи в статусе granted=true.

На текущий момент, я вижу 2 варианта решения:

1. Заменить ForeignKey на ManyToMany. Миграция проходит моментально,
   но решение тупое в хлам, ибо нарушает логику кода
2. Создавать индекс в обход миграций django с флагом CONCURRENTLY. Однако,
   очевидно, создаваться будет еще дольше, будет тормозить систему в
   целом. Как согласовать это с миграциями django тоже хороший вопрос.

Что посоветуете?

**Update:**

Исследовав ситуацию с миграциями Django, я выяснил, что Django позволяет делать неатомарные миграции (вне транзакции) только с версии 1.10, тогда как у нас используется 1.8 и обновить пока возможности нет (есть несовместимости). В то же время CREATE INDEX CONCURENTLY не может выполнятся в транзакции. Решение, которое я пока вижу - сделать в транзакции все, кроме индекса через [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runsql), а индекс сделать напрямую в БД.

Comment: Тормозить (с concurrently) лучше, чем совсем вешать, наверное. С миграциями согласуется нормально, т. к. оно для соединения, выполняющего миграцию, синхронное, просто другие соединения не блокирует. А у вас, возможно, [параллельное построение индекса ждало завершения пишущих транзакций](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY), и относится не к миграции, а к тому, что в это время в продукте происходило. У вас там долгие транзакции часто бывают?

Comment: 1) Ничего не происходило. Я специально поднял тестовую реплику боевой базы, на которой вообще нет нагрузки, кроме производимой миграции.

Comment: 2) Ну тормозить, конечно, лучше, чем вешать, но не намного =)

Comment: 3) Как выяснилось, с миграциями согласуется плохо. CONCURENTLY должно работать вне транзакции. А Django начала поддерживать неконкурентные транзакции только начиная с 1.10 (у нас 1.8 на проде). Сейчас добавлю изыскания в вопрос.

Comment: Подозреваю, что для создания этого индекса придётся сделать отдельную миграцию без оборачивания в транзакцию, если в Django такое можно сделать. Ну... я предполагаю, что это возможно. Мне слишком сильно хвалили джангу, чтобы я в это не верил .-.

Comment: Только с версии 1.10 они это добавили. В нашей среде (1.8) нельзя.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/#non-atomic-migrations

Comment: Это официальный штатный способ, но вряд ли единственный. Выполнять произвольный код до и после (хуки какие-нибудь) система миграций не позволяет?

Comment: Ну это уже не совсем миграции django. Я конечно могу закостылять чего-нибудь, но проще просто в БД запрос выполнить

Comment: Этот "запрос в БД" всё равно надо куда-то записать. А раз уж записывать, то куда-нибудь, где он сам и выполнится в нужный момент, чтобы никому не пришлось об этом напоминать или вспоминать. "Рядом с пустой миграцией" (если в джанге есть возможность сделать хук, даже если нештатно и разово) похоже на работоспособный вариант.